# fbauth2 is missing from your Info.plist

Tags: ios

I'm testing the Facebook SDK on iOS devices and I get this error when I press on the login button:

> 2018-11-11 22:27:57.543163+0100 swipethesquares[248:5302] Found
>   Facebook permission public_profile 2018-11-11 22:27:57.543420+0100
>   swipethesquares[248:5302] FacebookLogin:1 2018-11-11
>   22:27:57.543563+0100 swipethesquares[248:5302] Setting login status to
>   PROCESSING 2018-11-11 22:27:57.595283+0100 swipethesquares[248:5302]
>   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'InvalidOperationException', reason: 'fbauth2 is missing from your
>   Info.plist under LSApplicationQueriesSchemes and is required for iOS
>   9.0'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x1f97e7ef8 0x1f89b5a40 0x10307c230 0x104bd0de4 0x104bd2e44 0x10307b0ac 0x1030a459c 0x1030a499c
>   0x1030a4944 0x1030a3698 0x102b32570 0x1f97ef660 0x1f96cb980
>   0x102b923b4 0x102d3f1a8 0x102d384f4 0x102d1f39c 0x102d22078
>   0x102d21ed8 0x102b81954 0x102b81aa0 0x102b8e290 0x102b8e7fc
>   0x102cc99ec 0x102ccf6e0 0x102ccfcb8 0x102b8d7f8 0x102b8b1ec
>   0x10527966c 0x1fdc9d574 0x1f9a4758c 0x1f974f3e4 0x1f9776c30
>   0x1f977637c 0x1f9771134 0x1f97705b8 0x1fb9e4584 0x2265e4bc8
>   0x102dcd9cc 0x1f9230b94) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught
>   exception of type NSException (lldb)

I have read that I have to add "fbauth2" in the Info.plist file but my Info.plist file already has these lines:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key> 
<array>
<string>fbapi</string>   
<string>fb-messenger-api</string>  
<string>fbauth2</string>   
<string>fbshareextension</string>
<array>
```

any suggestion?

Thanks